# Like button from Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to get a facebook like button onto my site and it's not showing up at all:

I have this in my body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '62722122135',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=293758545460";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then I am trying to put this in my footer div towards the bottom of my site:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/edgehilluniversity?fref=ts" data-width="200" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

Comment: Beware!! use iframe is better than using these code. I tried these code and it doesn't work. But using iframe work fine

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3year Found a problem. Works! It is not necessary to use iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<script>`

```
      });
    };
/*from  there*/(function(d, s, id) {
```

And change

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=293758545460"
```

to

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=293758545460"
```

Comment: Do I need to declare anything in the css at all? @nicael

Comment: @user3565293 Error: "Failed to load resource"... Wait plz. Trying to solve.

Comment: @user3565293 Edited. Works!